# React-query request with parameters from react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm trying to make a request to the API with some specific parameters (in this case, `userName` and `listId`).

What comes to my mind first is the following:

```
const { userName, listId } = useParams();
const list = useQuery(["lists"], api.fetchList(userName, listId)); // This line is incorrect
```

Inside my API file, I'm doing something like this:

```
export const fetchList = async (userName, listId) =>
api.get(`/list/${userName}/${listId}`).then((res) => res.data);
```

how is it possible to actually achieve this?

Comment: this didnt work? Why? What the error you got?

Comment: @Alecell Hey! Just found why it was happening. I posted the solution.

Comment: why are you asking the same question multiple times? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388090/react-query-and-navigation-react-router-dom-returns-blank-pages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-query and navigation (react-router-dom) returns blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73388090/react-query-and-navigation-react-router-dom-returns-blank-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

When we are passing parameters, we will have to write this the following way:

```
const list = useQuery(["lists"], () => api.fetchList(listId));
```

(I had to remove userId since it's not necessary for my API).