# React-query and navigation (react-router-dom) returns blank pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-query

When I'm navigating between screens, react-query seems to struggle, as it ends up returning an `undefined`.

To give a better perspective of the issue, here is how the issue is formed:

I have two routes at the moment:

Home and List

Inside `Home` I have the following:

```
const lists = useQuery(["lists"], api.fetchLists);
...
{lists.isLoading && (
   <React.Fragment>
      <Skeleton />
   </React.Fragment>
)}

...
{isEmpty()}
```

Inside `isEmpty()`:

```
if (lists.data) {
      return lists.data.lists.length ? (
            {lists.data.lists?.map((list) => (
```

To navigate from home to `List`, I use

`` navigate(`/list/${list.id}`) ``

Once I navigate to `List` I do the following inside there:

```
const { listId } = useParams();
const list = useQuery(["lists"], () => api.fetchList(listId));
...
{list.isLoading ? (
        <Card style={{ padding: 30 }}>
          <div>
            <Skeleton />
          </div>
        </Card>
      ) : (
        {list.data}
      )}
```

So, when I navigate to `List`, the page goes blank. If I reload, everything loads normally. After a reload, if I try to go to `Home`, then `Home` goes blank and says `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same query key for fetching "all lists" and "a single list", so the caches are overriding each other. As a rule of thumb, always put all dependencies of the query function into the query key:

```
const { listId } = useParams();
const list = useQuery(["lists", listId], () => api.fetchList(listId));
```

if `listId` is potentially `undefined` on the first render, disable the query as long as it's not defined:

```
const { listId } = useParams();
const list = useQuery(
  ["lists", listId],
  () => api.fetchList(listId),
  { enabled: !!listId }
)
```